# Game Launcher and Updater for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So, I want to create a simple launcher for a game that I'm making for Windows. I want to write it on Visual Studio so it can do the following:

1. Launch the game wherever the .exe file is. (either via registry key or by the user selecting the destination)
2. Auto-install all the needed dependences for the game if they are missing or provide a link to install them.
3. Verify intergrity of the files.
4. Auto download the latest patch or take the user to the patch download site (optional).

In addition of these, I need some help on the following:

1. Assuming that I can set it up to download the patch, how can I deliver it? I'm not sure that the program can download files from SkyDrive can it?
2. How do I set it up as a 32-bit program? I have a 64-bit system here.
3. Is it possible to write a Metro version of the launcher using the same code?

Please note that the game will be in a "installable format". I'll be using Install Creator for this.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with ClickOnce?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, I prefer it as a standalone app. Although it could be useful if I pushed an update to it. The issue would be on how to update the launcher when it's hosted on OneDrive.

Comment: Well with ClickOnce, generally the launcher and the app are one and the same. The user runs the app and it updates itself, there is no "pushing" of updates.  However, for patching it might not be suitable because ClickOnce updates the whole thing even if you might want to patch a tiny portion.  [Read more about ClickOnce here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.120).ASPX)

Comment: So, it's best to make it as a standalone app, right? If yes, then how do I convert a ClickOnce app to a simple .exe file?

Comment: A ClickOnce app is already a "standalone...simple .exe file"

Answer (score 0):

I've written a similar software before for a game, that did almost the same things as you described. Given that you have not shown any code, I'll answer the 3 questions in a general, basic way.

1.) Depends on what you mean by patch. An installer that supposed to replace or extend existing files, delete old files, deploy new ones? In that case it's up to the installer to manage it. If a patch simply downloads a file and puts it in the right place you can download it from either Skydrive (DriveOne) or any other place. Check out the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive/) and the examples [here](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows).

2.) I'm not sure I understand this question, but I think you just want to compile your binary to 32bit in visual studio and that's it.

3.) Yes.

Comment: You mean a ClickOnce app that downloads the game and updates it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ClickOnce technology, but something like that. The question is what do YOU mean, because it was unclear in the question.

Comment: The patcher should download the new version of the game's files and replace the old ones including the launcher.

Comment: It's sounds simple then. Do you have a question about this?

Comment: Yes. How do I set it up and intergrate the API?

Comment: Create another question, with as many details as you can provide.